# Message in macro printed twice

Tags: macros, elisp, message

I wrote a function which can accept any kind, any number of arguments and so that it can print the name and value of the arguments. The function works as expected. But I don't like the function call requires me to pass a quote of value like this `(my-message 'emacs-version 'emacs-copyright)`. I want to simplified to `(my-message emacs-version emacs-copyright)`. Therefore I use macro to rewrite the function.

```
(defmacro my-message (&rest args)
  (if args
      (progn
        (message "This is the start of debug message.\n")
        (dolist (arg args)
          (cond
           ((stringp arg)
            (message arg))
           ((numberp arg)
            (message (number-to-string arg)))
           ((boundp arg)
            (pp arg)
            (message "")
            (pp (symbol-value arg)))
           ((not (boundp arg))
            (pp arg)
            (message "Undefined")))
          (message "\n"))
        (message "This is the end of debug message."))
    (message "This is a debug message ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")))
```

However, the some of the message are printed twice.

```
(my-message emacs-version emacs-copyright 12345 "HelloWorld" foobar)

This is the start of debug message.

emacs-version
"24.5.1"
 [2 times]
emacs-copyright
"Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc."
 [2 times]
12345
 [2 times]
HelloWorld
 [2 times]
foobar
Undefined
 [2 times]
This is the end of debug message.
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the message
`[2 times]`
in your output refers to an extra newline character.

This behavior can be reproduced by evaluating

```
(progn
  (message "HelloWorld")
  (message "\n"))
```

in *scratch*. The output in *messages* is

```
HelloWorld
[2 times]
"
"
```

I wonder if this behavior is intended.

Maybe I did misunderstand your question since my answer has nothing to do with macros.

Comment: This is the real reason of why `[2 times]` produced.

Answer (score 2):

You are using macros for a wrong reason.

A macro is not just a gimmick to avoid an extra character in your code.

Macros operate on code.
IOW, the code you wrote is executed at compile time (or macroexpansion time, if not compiled) and the result is then used instead of the macro form.

So, the symbol (and, more generally, sexp) section of your macro should look like

```
`(message "symbol: %s, value: %s" ',arg ,arg)
```

Read up on [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) if you don't understand the above.

However, let me repeat: macros are "advanced material" and you might prefer to avoid them until you are more comfortable with Lisp.

Comment: I always confused with macros. I tried complied the code and it gave expected result. What is the disadvantage of using a macro to generate the result. Although this is not directly answering the question, it points out another issue. So you got a +1 bonus from me.